# How PhysicsBodyLoader.SCALE of overlap2d runtime works?

Tags: java, libgdx, overlap2d

What is the purpose of that method is and when I have to use it? Really I have no idea. I also found the source code but that didn't help me much.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the source code, it appears to be used to help translate between "pixel units" and "world units".

[EDIT] [Xoppa's article][1](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/) explains it rather well, but "pixel units" is the number of pixels in your viewport. "world units" is what your game is actually measured in.

For example, suppose you have a table that is 1 meter (world unit) high. If it's far away, you may render it 10 pixels high; if you are closer it may be 100 pixels high. Moving closer changed how big you *perceived it to be*, and thus changed its pixel size, but didn't change how big it really was (its world unit size).

By default in vanilla libGDX these values are 1:1, but it is useful to keep them logically separate because that way you can change your display size without worrying about messing up your game height. If I know the chair is 1m high, I know a character who can jump 2m can jump over it regardless of how big I draw the character and the chair.

There are occasions where you might need to convert between the two (e.g. raycasting), and I imagine that is when scale would come in handy.

Comment: Uhm... thats right. But whats its the difference between "pixel units" and "world units"? And when I'm supposed to use it? When moving something in the game?

Comment: Did you try searching for pixel units vs world units? We have a lot of [existing Q&A on that very topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136990/39518) that might help you. :)